# How to delete backups of a volume from an APFS Time Machine snapshot?

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine

I recently reinstalled macOS Monterey (12.0.1) on my MacBook Air (Intel, 2020) and restored data from my Time Machine backup; APFS format.

That went well, but after I did this it seems like my external storage drive, named “Storage”, now has an older clone next to it called “Storage 1” in recent snapshots. See screenshot below of snapshot `2021-11-26-113550`.

I assume some kind of identifier for the system and drive itself changed when the restore happened. I am fine with that. But this fairly useless — and redundant — “Storage 1” is taking up about 700GB of space.

I can’t seem to just delete it as a Time Machine backup is “Read Only” to the Finder and Terminal since this is the newer Time Machine format that uses APFS and snapshots instead of HFS+ and a standard filesystem scheme.

What can I do to toss this “Storage 1” folder in the snapshots and free up that 700GB?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Time Machine to APFS (TMA), it is not possible to delete particular folders inside any Time Machine snapshots. This is the only downside of the change from TMH (Time Machine to HFS) to TMA.

It is possible to delete whole snapshots from TMA using `tmutil` command. I have done this under Big Sur, but I have seen some doubts cast on whether this is still possible for Monterey. But deleting whole snapshots is not what you are wanting.

I suggest you start with a new Time Machine disk/volume and, at some point, discard your old backups. With sufficient free space on your existing TM disk you can create a new volume in Disk Utility and start a new Time Machine backup to that. Otherwise you need another physical disk.

Comment: Each TM snapshot (like your 2021-11-26-113550) has content of volumes known to that backup snapshot. I would call `Storage` and `Storage 1` volumes inside the backup, but really that is just the way Finder presents pictorially the collection of folders and files that came from those particular source volumes.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Sadly, the right decision I think.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `tmutil associatedisk` to associate the old storage backup directory with the active drive and that will allow Time Machine to carry the old backup history and avoid the duplicate entry:

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk /Volumes/Storage "/Volumes/{TimeMachineDrive}/Backups.backupdb/{MachineDirectory}/Latest/Storage 1"
```

Or if you just want to get rid of the "Storage 1" backup and don't care about the history, you can use the earlier command, but instead, associate the "Storage 1" directory with a volume that is excluded from backups.

For example plug a USB drive e.g. `/Volumes/USB`, it should be automatically excluded from backups by Time Machine. Then you can run:

```
sudo tmutil associatedisk /Volumes/USB "/Volumes/{TimeMachineDrive}/Backups.backupdb/{MachineDirectory}/Latest/Storage 1"
```

In the next backup, Time Machine will wipe the "Storage 1" directory.